# Problem with Cyrillic letters

Tags: cyrillic

I used to write papers in English but now I have to type paper in Ukrainian. So I've got a couple of mistakes trying to make it.

Example

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
В рівноважній статистичній механіці.
\end{document}
```

Error

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:̆ not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Of course, I've searched a lot at TeX SX and also tried

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

and got

```
! Package ucs Error: Please activate option 'combine'.
```

While trying to use `\usepackage[combine]{ucs}` option I get the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package ucs.
! Package ucs Error: Please activate option 'combine'.
```

Any ideas what's wrong? Interesting fact that when I type text directly in TeX editor, everything is OK, but if I paste text from pdf I have these errors. Of course, you can advice me to type all the text but it's hard to type hundreds of pages on my own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pdflatex` is not able to handle combining accents; you should directly use U+0439 rather than the combination U+0438 and U+0306.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}

\begin{document}
В рівноважній статистичній механіці.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `babel` with more than one language option as in your case you should be aware of the following (babel manual version3.9r from 2016/4/23)

```
In multilingual documents, just use several option. So, in LATEX2e the preamble of
the document:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}
would tell LATEX that the document would be written in two languages, Dutch and
English, and that English would be the first language in use, and the main one.
```

`\usepackage[ukrainian,english]{babel}` would use the English language not the Ukrainian. The one typed last *i.e.* english would be the one selected, if you do not add a `\selectlanguage{ukrainian}` to your code.